# Tensorflow : Implementing gradient for user op in C++?

Tags: tensorflow

I'd ideally like the operation to be wholly self-contained (gradient and operation defined in same file). The official tutorial only highlights a python implementation. Does anyone know if it's possible to implement the gradient in C++, and how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic gradient computation is currently only fully supported in the Python API. So the association of an operation to its gradient operation should still be specified manually in Python. Suppose you have an op `Foo` and its gradient op `FooGrad` defined in C++, you should get the corresponding Python wrappers `foo` and `foo_grad`. In Python you can write the following:

```
@RegisterGradient("Foo"):
def _FooGrad(op, grad):
  return foo_grad(op.inputs[0], op.outputs[0], grad)
```

Note that I am assuming your `foo_grad` op takes the input and output of the original operation along with the incoming gradients. It may or may not be true for your case, so please adjust it accordingly.